# Jquery Not Working on loaded page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, single-page-application

i have a problem with jquery code. in this case i use library high chart. when the code put in one page there's no problem found. the script running well. like in this images

[working well](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQ01T.png)

but that's not what I want. in my case i use single page apps. and in making Single Page Apps I Use Angular JS Library. nah. here's in my problem. the jquery didn't running cause i loaded page when running page. so. when i click another menu the content load with another page.

this is jquery script i use for using high chart library :

```
    $(function () {
var chart;
$(document.body).ready(function() {
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container', //letakan grafik di div id container
            //Type grafik, anda bisa ganti menjadi area,bar,column dan bar
            type: 'line',  
            marginRight: 130,
            marginBottom: 25
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Pendapatan perkapita indonesia tahun 2006-2011',
            x: -20 //center
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'candra.web.id',
            x: -20
        },
        xAxis: { //X axis menampilkan data tahun 
            categories: ['2006', '2007', '2008','2009','2010','2011']
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {  //label yAxis
                text: 'pendapatan dalam USD'
            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080' //warna dari grafik line
            }]
        },
        tooltip: { 
        //fungsi tooltip, ini opsional, kegunaan dari fungsi ini 
        //akan menampikan data di titik tertentu di grafik saat mouseover
            formatter: function() {
                    return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                    this.x +': '+ this.y ;
            }
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            x: -10,
            y: 100,
            borderWidth: 0
        },
        //series adalah data yang akan dibuatkan grafiknya,
        //saat ini mungkin anda heran, buat apa label indonesia dikanan 
        //grafik, namun fungsi label ini sangat bermanfaat jika
        //kita menggambarkan dua atau lebih grafik dalam satu chart,
        //hah, emang bisa? ya jelas bisa dong, lihat tutorial selanjutnya 
        series: [{  
            name: 'Indonesia',  
            //data yang akan ditampilkan 
            data: [1660, 1946,2271,2590,3004,3550]
        }]
    });
});
```

});

and for calling that script i use this code in html:

```
  <div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

please help me. cause this also happen in another library.
Thanks

Comment: .. What's the problem? What are you expecting to see, and what are you actually seeing? Are you getting any errors in your console when running the page?

Comment: Where are you loading the jquery? What's not executing?

Comment: remove this one $(document.body).ready(function() {}

Comment: @Lee i don't know what's the problem. the jquery script can't work in my dynamic page. i check console. there's no error.

Comment: @Adjit in external file. i give name customjs.js i don't know maybe jquery don't work on dynamic page.

Comment: @IsmailFarooq i have tried to remove that's code. still not function.

Comment: jQuery works on dynamic pages, you just have to setup your selectors properly. You don't need `$(document.body).ready(function(){});` because that is the same thing as `$(function(){});` so you are being redundant. Pick one or the other. Also, open your console up and type in `$.fn.jquery` and it will let you know what version of jQuery is currently loaded in the window. If jQuery isn't loaded then it will return undefined. This will at least let you know that the order of things is what is causing the issue

Comment: @Adjit i using jquery version 2.1.4

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use an AngularJS Highcharts [Adapter](http://www.highcharts.com/blog/194-using-highcharts-with-angular-js) rather than invoking Highcharts with jQuery.

You are always going to run into problems using jQuery outside of AngularJS. In most cases jQuery should not be needed in an AngularJS SPA application.

Comment: thanks for your reference. do you have similar reference for daterangepicker bootstrap and angular js? cause daterangepicker didn't work in my SPA.

Comment: Yes. Instead of using the Bootstrap.JS file, use the native angularJS Bootstrap directives: https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/